Angular component not disposed after OnDestroy
I have a component with a signal state:
array: WritableSignal<string[]> = signal([]);
I want the array to be removed from browser memory because the array can get quite big, and the component may be removed from view and then added again.
I have checked the browser memory tab, there is a new instance of the component every time it is shown in view, and they are all stored.
I want the behavior where the component is destroyed and it's removed from browser memory.

multiple ways dear, this.array.destroy() or set your component strategy to onPush

We'll need more code to understand what is happenning. And potentially a stackblitz repro.
